# Explicit wait is not accepting webelement

Tags: automated-tests

Iam using Page object model ...if i declare element like this

```
@FindBy(xpath=" ")
Public WebElement element;
```

Then I am unable to use explicit wait

```
Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element):
```

explicit wait is not accepting webelement. Can anyone help me on how to pass webelement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be two methods for each condition, one `visibilityOfElementLocated` and other `visibilityOfElement`. The first one accepts By object and later one accept element.

For your case you pass, you have to use method name which doesn't end with word Located.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))
```

Comment: Is there any possibility for giving webelement to ExpectedConditons.visibilityOfElementLocated (element)

Comment: Nope. for passing element. you can to use ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()? It does the same job